# Since Spellforge is gone, what Spellbook management software is available?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, tool-recommendation

I want to be able to manage my Sorceror's "spellbook" on my computer and print a nice list of spells, and ideally descriptions. We level up very frequently compared to normal (accelerated campaign), so I don't want to do it by hand.

Older forum posts all seem to reference Spellforge, and I use Heroforge for my character sheet, but the developer seems to have fallen ill and abandoned the project and server.

Comment: Spellforge's site might be down temporarily or permanently, but Spellforge can still be accessed. See the answers in the linked question.

Comment: Wow, I'm amazed to find a 2 year old question that is up to date, I guess I'm too used to other StackExchanges.

Thanks all.

Comment: If you look at the edit histories, I went investigating after I saw your question and updated the relevant answers. ;) There's no shame in unknowingly making a duplicate either, because it catches different Google searches and help us help more people.